# Store much Data in the CDocument class in MFC

Tags: view, architecture, mfc, document, mdi

How can I store in a MDI Application (MFC) much data in the Document (CDocument) class? There is no database or something. I've got a dialog where I can type in adresses. This adresses must be stored. 
I hope you understand my question.

Sincerely

Comment: You can store your data in whatever member variables of your CDocument derived class, for example in an array. I suggest you go through some MFC tutorial first, there are plenty of them, just search "MFC tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

Your CDocument derived class should access and store the data needed by your app. It can do this with member variables (appropriate data structures) that you add or it can do it via a database if you want a database. For example, the MSDN sample named ENROLL shows a CDocument that manages the connection to a database.